# Create Response with Location header in JAX-RS

Tags: java, c#, jax-rs

I have classes auto-generated in NetBeans with RESTful template from entities, with CRUD functions (annotated with POST, GET, PUT, DELETE). I have a problem with *create* method, which after inserting an entity from the frontend, I would like *create* to update a response so that my view will automatically (or asynchronously, if that's the right term) reflect the added entity.

I came across this (example) line of code but written in C# (of which I know nothing about):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", "api/tasks" +value.Id);
```

Using JAX-RS in Java, is there anyway to get the current HttpContext just like in C# and to manipulate the header?

The closest I came about is

```
Response.ok(entity).header("Location", "api/tasks" + value.Id);
```

and this one certainly is not working. It seems I need to get the current HttpContext before building the Response.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think you mean to do something like `Response.created(createdURI).build()`. This will create a response with a [201 Created](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status, with the `createdUri` being the location header value. Normally this is done with POSTs. On the client side, you can call `Response.getLocation()` which will return the new URI.

From the [Response API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)

- [`public static Response.ResponseBuilder created(URI location)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created%28java.net.URI%29) - Create a new ResponseBuilder for a created resource, set the location header using the supplied value.
- [`public abstract URI getLocation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getLocation%28%29) - returns the location URI, otherwise null if not present.

Keep in mind about the `location` you specify to the `created` method:

> the URI of the new resource. If a relative URI is supplied it will be converted into an absolute URI by resolving it relative to the request URI.

If you don't want to rely on static resource paths, you could get the current uri path from the [`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) class. You could do something like

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response createCustomer(Customer customer, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        int customerId = // create customer and get the resource id
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        uriBuilder.path(Integer.toString(customerId));
        return Response.created(uriBuilder.build()).build();
    }
}
```

This would create the location `.../customers/1` (or whatever the `customerId` is), and send it as the response header

Note if you want to send the entity along with the response, you can just attach the [`entity(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#entity%28java.lang.Object%29) to the method chain of the `Response.ReponseBuilder`

```java
return Response.created(uriBuilder.build()).entity(newCustomer).build();
```

Comment: This UriInfo-solution does not work if path parameters are used for the resource creation. Any suggestions on how to approach such a case? UriInfo does not seem to offer a straightforward method to get the full path, but without any pathparams.

Comment: @Senshi not sure what you mean. Can you post another question with an example. I'm sure there's a solution, but I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sure I can. Would appreciate your input :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/52773898/2436002

Comment: Hi This UriInfo class works with jax/rs is there is anything which gives same functionality for spring i have searched it now i am creating with servletContext which is not as good as former one.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @POST
public Response addMessage(Message message, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws URISyntaxException
{
    System.out.println(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath());

    Message newmessage = messageService.addMessage(message);

    String newid = String.valueOf(newmessage.getId()); //To get the id

    URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(newid).build();

    return Response.created(uri).entity(newmessage).build();
}
```