# Return result of create method and 201 status code

Tags: java, web-services, rest

How can i return the result of create method in rest api and also 201 status code? In this code the status code is 200 how can i change it to 201?

```
    Path("/student")    
    public class MyRestApi{

    @Path("/create")
    public Response create(){
           Student student = new Student;
           //insert in data source
           Return Response.ok(student).build();
          }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ResponseBuilder.status(int)` OR `Response.status(int)` method and send it like :-

```
Response.ok(student).status(201).build(); // 201 is the response code
```

OR

```
Response.status(201).ok(student).build(); // 201 is the response code
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the ResponseBuilder together with the readable Status enum:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
[...]
return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity("created the student" 
    + "- this is your customized message to the caller").build();
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but if anyone else should stumble upon this question... the [answer supplied here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26094619/2197048) that uses the [created method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created-java.net.URI-) would seem to be more appropriate since it uses methods designed for returning responses when creating resources and neither hardcodes the response code nor requires another call to set the Location header.

An excerpt from that answer:

> From the [Response API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html)
>
> [public static Response.ResponseBuilder created(URI location)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created-java.net.URI-) -
>   Create a new ResponseBuilder for a created resource, set the location
>   header using the supplied value.

Comment: Answers that consist of a few links and little text are not good for SO. You should provide a brief synopsis why the referenced material addresses the question posed.