# JAX-RS, JAXB implementation to create a simple object and test

Tags: java, web-services, junit, jaxb, jax-rs

I am learning to implement web service using JAX-RS and JAXB, however I couldn't get this to work. The idea is to have a web service that can create a customer(with customer name) and store them in a Hash Map. I tried to create test as well but the test failed with error

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke
>       (ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)at
>       org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke
>       (ClientInvocation.java:407)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.post
>       (ClientInvocationBuilder.java:195)
>       at BloggerTest.addCustomer(StoreTest.java:65)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  
>       The Failure  Trace says `Caused by :javax.ws.rs ProcessingException: 
>       could not find writer for content-type application/xml type: store.domain.Customer

which I don't quite understand.

So below is what I have got at the moment, I'm using the "return singletons" to create instance of the store class: 
A Store class:

```
public class Store {
private Map<String, Customer> _customer;

public Store() {
     _customer = new ConcurrentHashMap <String,Customer>();
}
    //assume the incoming http request contains customer name
   @Post 
   @Consumes("application/xml")
   public Response createCustomer (Customer customer){
        _customer.put(customer.getName(), customer);
       return Response.created( URI.create("/customers/" + customer.getName()))
              .build();
   }
 }
```

And a class that runs test:

```
public class StoreTest {

private static final String WEB_SERVICE_URI = "http://localhost:10000/services/store";

private static Client _client;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClient() {
    _client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
}
@Before
public void reloadServerData() {
    Response response = _client
            .target(WEB_SERVICE_URI).request()
            .put(null);
    response.close();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

@AfterClass
public static void destroyClient() {
    _client.close();
}

@Test   
public void addCustomer() {
    Customer BartSimpsons = new Customer ("BartSimpsons");//create a new customer with name
    Response response = _client
            .target(WEB_SERVICE_URI).request()
            .post(Entity.xml(BartSimpsons)); 

    String location = response.getLocation().toString();
      response.close();

      Customer BartCreated = _client.target(location).request()
            .accept("application/xml").get(Customer.class);
  //check if the Customer created by the service has the same name with the original customer
      assertEquals(BartSimpsons.getName(), BartCreated.getName());
  }
}
```

I feel that I am missing some important points here, but I really couldn't figure how what I did wrong with the annotations or something else. Can someone please help? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `@XmlRootElement` on the `Customer` class, _and_ also a no-arg constructor for the `Customer` class?

Comment: Thanks. No and no. I used a user name ("BartSimpsons") to create a user, and I thought JAXB has a default way to convert object to XML, if we don't specify `XmlRootElement`?

Comment: The `@XmlRootElement` is needed. Also without the no-arg, on the sever side, JAXB won't be able to construct it, and you will get another exception. The current exception you are facing in on the client. So the request is not even reaching the server.

Comment: @peeskillet  I added a no-arg constructor and `@XmlRootElement`. This time I got a HTTP404 not found exception from the test. Have you got any ideas about this? It seems heading to the right direction..

Comment: @peeskillet It seems that the test didn't generate the uri for the customer

Comment: Where do the two path segments `services/store` come from? Does the `Store` class have `@Path("/store")`? Does the `Application` subclass have `@ApplicationPath("/services")` or is `/services` configured somewhere else like in a web.xml? Are you able to access a `GET` endpoint from the browswer? That should give you an idea of the required URL. Just add a different `@GET` method in the `Store` class and try to access it from a simple browser. Also is this a typo `@Post`? Because it should be upper case. If you copy and pasted it, I am not sure where you got the lowerase `@Post` from

Comment: @peeskillet Thank you so much. Now in the test the uri is created"http:// localhost:10000/services/users/BartSimpsons" But I still got a HTTP404 not found exception. I am really confused... Could you help to throw light on this?  btw yes the `@POST` is in upper case. The store class implemented a interface and I put the `@POST` there. I didn't include that part in the question, otherwise it'd be too long..

Comment: If you are saying what I think you're saying, i.e. "the request is successful but when you try to access the created uri you get a 404", then you are missing the idea of how it works. There is no endpoint dynamically created on the server. You need to have another endpoint, with `@GET @Path("/{id}")` and you need to look up the name by the id then return the object.

Comment: @peeskillet yes I think what happened was like you said. I tried to access the object using Customer BartCreated = _client.target(location).request() .accept("application/xml").get(Customer.class); I have a `@GET @Path("{name}") @Produces("application/xml")  ` before method `Customer GetCustomer(@PathParam("name") String name)` but I couldn't work out why the @GET method is not being called.

Comment: Try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26094619/2587435) for the post method. Maybe the uri is not created correctly. In the client code, I would not cast directly to `Customer` but instead return `Response`. That way you can at least do some debugging with status codes and such

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. Using @Produces annotation over my service method helped me to resolve the problem. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought @Produces is for Get request? Could you explain which method should I put it over?

Comment: Like "@Consumer" tells your method that what content type your method is going to consume similarly "@Produces" tells your method what content type it is going to return. Use it at createCustomer method. And I think you are returning xml as a response so set it to "application/xml".