# rest/javax/jersey/grizzly: is it mandatory to return OK (200) response code for POST requests?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, grizzly

Imagine a post REST end point such as:

```
@POST
@Path("/cbo/{param1}/{param2}")
public Response updateCbo() {
    //do something
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

My question is: if everything goes well, is it better to return the OK response or is it the default anyway? I see the GET queries are usually not bothering returning the response, just the requested content, and web clients do fetch a `200 OK` header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to return a response at all, let's say if you have a `POST` (or any other function) type call that in the response request you want to return a String (or any object for that matter if you are using a serializer like Jackson)

You can just do:

```
@POST
@Path("/cbo/{param1}/{param2}")
public String updateCbo() {
    //do something
    return "My Response"
}
```

Jersey will automatically return 200 for this. If you set the function to void, Jersey will automatically return 204 (Success - no content).

If you want the call to fail you can just raise an exception.

Answer (score 3):

When POSTing to *create* a new resource, the general accepted away is to send back a [201 Created](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) status, with the `Location` header set the URI of the new resource. You can see an example of one to accomplish this, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26094619/2587435).

If you are just *updating* a resource, which rather than POST, is generally done with PUT, then instead of a 201, the general way is to send a 204 No Content, on success. Example

```
@PUT
@Path("/cbo/{param1}/{param2}")
public Response updateCbo(Model updated,
                          @PathParam("param1") String param1,
                          @PathParam("param2") String param2) {
    Model model = modelServive.lookup(param1, param2);
    if (model == null) 
        return Response.notFound().build();
    model = PropTranferUtils.transfer(model, updated);
    modelService.update(model);
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```