# Jax-RS Response.created(location) for routes with path parameters

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a REST route to create a resource that uses path parameters.

The answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26094619/2436002
shows how to easily create a proper location header for the response using the UriInfo Context.

```
@Path("/resource/{type}")
public class Resource {
    @POST
    public Response createResource(@PathParam("type") String type, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) 
    {
        UUID createdUUID = client.createResource(type);
        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        builder.path(createdUUID.toString());
        return Response.created(builder.build()).build();
    }
}
```

However, this includes the path parameters in the received URI, which will not lead to the proper resource.

POST: http://localhost/api/resource/{type} with pathparam type = "system"

will return http://localhost/api/resource/system/123 (123 being the generated id)
while the proper URI would be
http://localhost/api/resource/123

So, how can I get the proper resource location to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, doing it the way in the link, you assume a parent child relationship, where you are posting to a collection endpoint and a child single resource is created. With your use case, this isn't the case. One way you can make it work is to just use `UriBuilder.fromResource()`. Then just call `resolveTemplate()` to put in the value for `"type"`.

```java
URI createdUri = UriBuilder.fromResource(Resource.class)
       .resolveTemplate("type", createdUUID.toString()).build();
return Response.created(uri).build();
```

This will give you `http://localhost/api/resource/123`

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question. But as my actual class contained multiple methods, I couldn't use fromResource. But it got me on the right track, and fromMethod(Resource.class, "methodname") worked great!